# Errors in sending emails with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm programming a site, and this site have a contact form, but i'am have problems with this.

the code returned this error.

'Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.'

code below:

```
$this->load->library('email'); 
    $config = Array(
         'protocol' => 'smtp',
         'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
         'smtp_port' => 587,
         'smtp_user' => '', // change it to yours
         'smtp_pass' => '', // change it to yours
         'mailtype' => 'html',
         'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
         'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );      
    $this->email->initialize($config); 

    $dados = $this->input->post();
    $this->email->from('', "Admin Team");
    $this->email->to("test@domainname.com");
    $this->email->subject("This is test subject line");
    $this->email->message("Mail sent test message...");
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 

    if($this->email->send()){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Email enviado com sucesso!');
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$this->email->print_debugger());
    }
    $this->load->view('includes/head.php');
    $this->load->view('home/contato.php');
```

thanks for the help

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972179/unable-to-send-email-using-php-mail-your-server-might-not-be-configured-to-se

Comment: thanks for the help, the code worked. :)